# In a quarto book, how to remove the chapter number in a figure or table crossreference?

Tags: r, quarto

I'm writing different chapters in a quarto book. When I reference a figure or table in a chapter, the chapter number is included. For example, figure 1 in chapter 2 will be "Figure 2.1" and table 2 in chapter 3 will be "Table 3.2". Is there a way to remove the chapter reference? I want the numbers to restart in each chapter, so each chapter can have a "Figure 1" or "Table 2". I do not need to reference figures/ tables from another chapter (so in chapter 2 I wont reference to figure 1 in chapter 3, for example).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
crossref:
  chapters: false
```

in your `_quarto.yml` to turn of cross-reference between chapters.